# Finding Finite vs. Infinite Interections

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, elementary-set-theory

> T/F: Let $A_n$ = $(0, \frac{1}{n})$ (a bounded set), and $B_n$ = [$n, \infty)$ (a closed set). Any finite intersection of $A_n$'s and $B_n$'s is non-empty, but the infinite intersection of $A_n$'s and $B_n$'s is empty.

I think the answer is true, but my logic behind it is a bit iffy. Does it involve limits? This is my reasoning: As $n \rightarrow k$, where $k$ is some finite number, then $(0, \frac{1}{k})$ and $B_n$ = [$k, \infty)$ have finitely many numbers in it. So, we have a finite intersection of finite numbers, which makes it non-empty. On the other hand, As $n \rightarrow \infty$, then $(0, \frac{1}{\infty})$ and $B_n$ = [$\infty, \infty)$, then they're approaching "emptiness"? I can't really grasp the ideas behind these finite/infinite intersections, so any clarification would be tremendously helpful. Thank you.

Comment: I suggest you forget about limits for the moment.

Comment: What should I be using/thinking of to understand this problem?

Comment: $(0,1/k)$ and $(k,\infty)$ do not "have finitely many numbers in it." Both are infinite sets. Note that if $n_1 < n_2 < \cdots < n_k$, then $A_{n_1} \cap A_{n_2} \cap \cdots \cap A_{n_k} = A_{n_k}$, and $B_{n_1} \cap B_{n_2} \cap \cdots \cap B_{n_k} = B_{n_k}$, so both intersections are nonempty. Why does this argument fail if we intersect infinitely many $A$'s or $B$'s?

Comment: Does it involve countability/uncountability arguments?

Comment: P.S. Both parentheticals are incorrect. $A_n = (0,1/n)$ is not a closed set, and $B_n = [n, \infty)$ is not a bounded set (unless you're using something other than the usual topology on $\mathbb R$). In any case, topological concepts are irrelevant to the question being asked.

Comment: Oops, I re-read the problem and had them mixed around. $A_n$ is bounded, $B_n$ is closed.

Comment: For such problems you should NEVER think with limits..its just wrong..if i gave you for instance $A_n=((-1)^n,+\infty)$ to compute an infinite intersection or union what would you do then?..the limit  might not exist but it does make sence to  talk about finite or infinite intersections or unions because they always exist (empty or nonempty)

Answer (score 2):

**True**

1. Let $x \in \bigcap\limits_n A_n$, then $x > 0$, but $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$, hence there exist rational $0 < \frac{p}{q} < x$ and obviously $\frac{1}{q} \leq \frac{p}{q}$, i.e. $x \notin A_p$ and hence $x \notin \bigcap\limits_n A_n$. Contradiction. Hence, $\bigcap\limits_n A_n = \emptyset$.
2. Let $x \in \bigcap\limits_n B_n$. Trivially, $x < \lceil{x}\rceil + 1$, hence $x \notin B_{\lceil{x}\rceil + 1}$ and then not in $\bigcap\limits_n B_n$. Same conclusion follows.